# How can i create buttons in C#

Tags: c#, class, button, inheritance

Please, can you help me with create buttons. I have problem that when i run application so i dont see any buttons from my code. Somewhere in my code is bug.

**Step 1) (Class for button properities)**

```
class GraphicClassStructure : GraphicPosition
{
    public Button menu = new Button();
    public Button classBackround = new Button();
    public Button resetTree = new Button();

    public void CreateClassButtons()
    {
        switch (UniqueValue.character)
        {
            case "sorcerer":
                this.menu.Name = "sorcererText";
                this.menu.BackgroundImage = BuildResource.sorcerer;
                this.classBackround.BackgroundImage = BuildResource.sorcerer_skill_tree;
                break;
            case "dragonknight":
                this.menu.Name = "dragonKnightText";
                this.menu.BackgroundImage = BuildResource.dragonknight;
                this.classBackround.BackgroundImage = BuildResource.dragonknight_skill_tree;
                break;
            case "templar":
                this.menu.Name = "templarText";
                this.menu.BackgroundImage = BuildResource.templar;
                this.classBackround.BackgroundImage = BuildResource.templar_skill_tree;
                break;
            case "nightblade":
                this.menu.Name = "nightbladeText";
                this.menu.BackgroundImage = BuildResource.nightblade;
                this.classBackround.BackgroundImage = BuildResource.nightblade_skill_tree;
                break;
        }

        // Menu
        this.menu.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        this.menu.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Stretch;
        this.menu.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
        this.menu.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        this.menu.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        this.menu.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
        this.menu.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(Location[0][0][0], Location[0][1][0]);
        this.menu.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(Size[0][0][0], Size[0][1][0]);
        this.menu.TabIndex = 3;
        this.menu.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;

        // Class Backround
        this.classBackround.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        this.classBackround.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Stretch;
        this.classBackround.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
        this.classBackround.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        this.classBackround.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        this.classBackround.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
        this.classBackround.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(Location[0][0][1], Location[0][1][1]);
        this.classBackround.Name = "classBackround";
        this.classBackround.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(Size[0][0][1], Size[0][1][1]);
        this.classBackround.TabIndex = 17;
        this.classBackround.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;

        // Reset tree
        this.resetTree.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        this.resetTree.BackgroundImage = BuildResource.reset;
        this.resetTree.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Stretch;
        this.resetTree.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
        this.resetTree.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        this.resetTree.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        this.resetTree.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
        this.resetTree.Name = "resetTree";
        this.resetTree.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(Size[0][0][2], Size[0][1][2]);
        //this.resetTree.TabIndex = 18;
        this.resetTree.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
    }
}
```

**Step 2) (Class for button position and size)**

```
class GraphicPosition
{
    // new int[type][x,y][value]
    // Location
    public int[][][] Location;

    // Size
    public int[][][] Size;

    public GraphicPosition()
    {
        Location = new int[][][]
        {
            new int[][]
            {
                // Menu
                new int[89],
                // Class
                new int[325],
                // Reset Tree
                new int[410],
                new int[615],
                new int[823]
            },
            new int[][]
            {
                // Menu
                new int[223],
                // Class
                new int[200],
                // Reset Tree
                new int[169],
                new int[169],
                new int[169]
            }
        };
        Size = new int[][][]
        {
            new int[][]
            {
                // Menu
                new int[133],
                // Class
                new int[619],
                // Reset Tree
                new int[28]
            },
            new int[][]
            {
                // Menu
                new int[26],
                // Class
                new int[484],
                // Reset Tree
                new int[25]
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**Step 3) (Script in form initialization component)**

```
    Collection collection = new Collection();
    GraphicClassStructure classStructure = new GraphicClassStructure();

    public buildEditor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Cursor = NativeMethods.LoadCustomCursor(Path.Combine(collection.source, collection.cursor));
        maxSkillPoint.Text = collection.maxSkill.ToString();
        classStructure.CreateClassButtons();
        this.Controls.Add(classStructure.classBackround);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            switch (i)
            {
                case 0:
                    classStructure.resetTree.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(classStructure.Location[0][0][2], classStructure.Location[0][1][2]);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    classStructure.resetTree.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(classStructure.Location[0][0][3], classStructure.Location[0][1][3]);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    classStructure.resetTree.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(classStructure.Location[0][0][4], classStructure.Location[0][1][4]);
                    break;
            }
            classStructure.resetTree.Click += new EventHandler(resetTreekOneEvent_Click);
            classStructure.resetTree.Tag = i;
            this.Controls.Add(classStructure.resetTree);
        }

        switch (UniqueValue.character)
        {
            case "sorcerer":
                MessageBox.Show("sorcerer");
                classStructure.menu.Click += new System.EventHandler(sorcerer_Click);
                classStructure.menu.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(sorcerer_MouseEnter);
                classStructure.menu.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(sorcerer_MouseLeave);
                break;
            case "dragonknight":
                MessageBox.Show("dragonknight");
                classStructure.menu.Click += new System.EventHandler(dragonKnightText_Click);
                classStructure.menu.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(dragonKnightText_MouseEnter);
                classStructure.menu.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(dragonKnightText_MouseLeave);
                break;
            case "templar":
                MessageBox.Show("templar");
                classStructure.menu.Click += new System.EventHandler(templar_Click);
                classStructure.menu.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(templar_MouseEnter);
                classStructure.menu.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(templar_MouseLeave);
                break;
            case "nightblade":
                MessageBox.Show("nightblade");
                classStructure.menu.Click += new System.EventHandler(nightblade_Click);
                classStructure.menu.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(nightblade_MouseEnter);
                classStructure.menu.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(nightblade_MouseLeave);
                break;
        }
        this.Controls.Add(this.classStructure.menu);
    }
```

Any buttons is not displayed. Please, help me.

Comment: `Somewhere in my code is bug.` debug it then, it might help you. Try to minimize an amount of code you are dealing with and you will soon find a culprit.

Comment: From the code you posted, I cannot see where the buttons are added to the form. Use the designer to add buttons for beginning. Dynamically creating buttons is an advanced task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your buttons have size (0, 0) and location (0, 0).
You use arrays incorrectly. E.g. the code `new int[89]` creates an array of 89 elements and all the elements are zero. But it looks like you wanted to store a single `int` value 89.
You need to change your code in such a way:
**Declaration**:

```
// 2 pairs of square brackets instead of 3
public int[][] Location;
public int[][] Size;
```

**Initialization**:

```
Location = new int[][]
{
    new int[]
    {
        // Menu
        89,
        // Class
        325,
        // Reset Tree
        410,
        615,
        823
    },
...
```

**Use:**

```
    this.menu.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(Location[0][0], Location[1][0]);
```

But better way is to redesign your Location and Size data structures in such a way:

```
Point[] Location; // instead of int[][] Location
Size[] Size; // instead of int[][] Size
```

Comment: Your solution helped me, really thx and i use your opinion for point and size.